# enable ssl for mysql and postgres databases: python, sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I want to enable ssl for my two types, `mysql` and `postgres` for database connections. I have certificate files in my repository and running my code on docker with these certificates. I am using the following code:

```
            uri = "{0}://{1}@{2}:{3}/{4}".format(db_creds.get('scheme'),
                                                 self._get_auth_str(db_creds.get('username'),
                                                                    db_creds.get('password')),
                                                 db_creds.get('hostname'),
                                                 str(db_creds.get('port')),
                                                 db_creds.get('name'))
            ssl_args = {}
            if db == 'mysql':
                if self.config['ssloption'] == 'true':
                    self.config['ssloption'] = 'required'
                ssl_args = {
                    'ssl': {
                        'sslmode': str(self.config['ssloption'])
                    }
                }
            if db == 'warehouse':
                if self.config['ssloption'] == 'true':
                    self.config['ssloption'] = 'require'
                ssl_args = {
                    "sslmode": str(self.config['ssloption'])
                }
            self._connections[db] = create_engine(uri, connect_args=ssl_args, encoding='utf8')
```

I have tried all options available in documentations online but I can't find a generic way to do it for both types of databases. I want to know how I can achieve perfection in this.